# List or extract file from recursive archived file without fully extraction

Tags: python, gzip, 7zip, php-ziparchive

Is there a way to list all files without extracting all the files?
AFAIK, current tools can list dirs/files, but can't handle nested archives.
E.g., can I list all the files in archive.tar.gz, and extract only file4 w/o extracting all the files?
I think theoretically it can be done by parsing the archive headers and extracting desired files only, but before I start to do this from scratch, I'd like to know if there are any existing tools/libs to do this.
Thanks.

```
archive.tar.gz
    |----file1
    |----dir1
    |       |----file2
    |----archive1.tar
            |----file3
            |----archive2.tar.bz2
                    |----file4
```

Comment: To get to file4, you'll have to extract archive1 and archive2. Maybe you can write code to do this extraction in memory, without writing the nested archives to the filesystem. But you'll have to extract them somehow to get at their table of contents and the content.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll dig some more into archive headers. Some GUI archive tools, such as 7zFM, can open recursive archived files like a file explorer, not sure if they extracted files to some temp path or just poking the archive heads.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the list command of 7-Zip? I'm not sure if this works with .tar files and I don't have one to test on. However, if you look in the help files in 7-Zip under command line commands you'll find the list option and the switches that go with it. There basic example is:

```
7z l archive.zip
```

However, yours will probably look more like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "\\Server\Folder\Archive.7z" "-ir!OurPrograms\TestFile.txt"
```

I'm currently trying to figure out how to do something via the list command in vbscript. If you want to checkout the thread, here's the link: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2127324-file-exists-in-7-zip-archive

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes I tried 7z commands, but it can't work directly on nested archives.